# How to extract an apk with all updates?

Tags: android, apk

I tried to use one of these `Apk Extractor` found on play store, but when the apk is extracted its just 80mb while its full size with all updates is 1GB+

How i could extract an apk with all of its updates ? I'm trying to reinstall the apk on another device with all of its update.

How does websites like [apkpure](https://apkpure.com/) provide the apk with all updates to download?

I mean how i could get the updated apk link, i would like to not rely on downloading the apk from such sites

Comment: What do you mean by "updates"? You always have only one version of an app installed, so updates will overwrite/replace old versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install an app (e.g. on your other device), you only need the latest version, but not the previous ones. This is because a new version always contains the old version, plus some new changes. You can therefore obtain the app from the Play Store on your other device as normal, you do not need to copy it from your first device.

And by the way: Your apk extractor works as it should.